# My windows store application not getting certified

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have made a simple video player application for windows store. I have completed the other formalities and Submitted the app on the store, but I am getting the message

> Certification Report
>
> Overall result: failed
>
> Report generated at 8/19/2014 2:18 PM UTC
>
> Windows 8
>
> Security tests: incomplete
>
> This test scans your app for malware and unwanted behaviors. Learn more

Well, now when I went to update the SDK I am getting this message.  See the end of this message for details on invoking

```
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Class not registered
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18449 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
appcertlite
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Windows%20Kits/8.0/App%20Certification%20Kit/appcertlite.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.AE.Windows
    Assembly Version: 6.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.2.9200.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Windows%20Kits/8.0/App%20Certification%20Kit/Microsoft.AE.Windows.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.AE
    Assembly Version: 6.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.2.9200.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Windows%20Kits/8.0/App%20Certification%20Kit/Microsoft.AE.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.9200.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Windows%20Kits/8.0/App%20Certification%20Kit/Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
appcertlite.resources
    Assembly Version: 6.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.2.9200.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Windows%20Kits/8.0/App%20Certification%20Kit/en/appcertlite.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34107 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

   



> Technical compliance: failed

> This tests your app with the Windows App Certification Kit. You can also run this the test locally from the SDK. Learn more
One or more of the Windows App Certification Kit tests failed. Test your app with the Windows App Certification Kit on your computer to get more detailed info about this error.
```

Also before submitting the app I am performing the tests with the kit provided from my SDK, where the tests are declared as PASSED. I have gone through my code many times and don't have idea that what had went wrong. Below is the source code of my main.xaml.cs page.

Comment: Have you kept your SDK fully updated? Are there updates to the tests that you need to download?

Comment: Have you made sure that the kit you used to test your code was the most up to date version?

Comment: Yes, the sdk was asking for update, but I didn't updated it and followed along the already installed one. Does this really is a problem.

Comment: Well, now when I went to update the SDK I am getting this message.